# Make own rule for multiplication

Tags: functions, function-construction

I'm new to mathematica, so I still cannot use it properly. I want to do symbolic programming.

My question is : is there any way to define our own multiplication. Suppose $a,b$ are arbitrary variables, I want to define $ba=qab$ as the rule, with $q$ is some constant. Then if a compute $baab$, then I want the result become $baab=qabab=q^{2}aabb=q^{2}a^{2}b^{2}$ (I swap the position of the first $b$ from left to $a$ two times).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You might consider using `NonCommutativeMultiply[]` in your implementation.

Comment: I'll try to look at that command and how it works then

Comment: yes, I want the general rules to be $ba=qab$, so the multiplication is not commutative.

Comment: Can all the q's move all the way to the left in any expression? $-$ that is, do they commute with `a` and `b`?

Comment: yes, $q$ is some constant, so $q$ commute with $a$ and $b$.

Comment: It seems that everyone is interpreting this question in a different way. Are you after such replacement rules: `b ** a ** a ** b //. {b ** a -> q a ** b, 
  x___ ** (q_ y_) ** z___ :> q x ** y ** z} (* q^2 a ** a ** b ** b *)`?

Comment: yes, I want every $ba$ be replaced by $qab$. $baab=q^{2}a^{2}b^{2}$ is just the example that happen because I replace $ba$ to be $qab$. But, actually I want to make this rules happen to every multiplication, I mean that if I have $babaa$, it is equal to $q^{5}a^{3}b^{2}$, or $babba=q^{4}a^{2}b^{3}$, etc.

Comment: @R.Kasyfil Please [ping users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), when replying to their comments, so that they will be notified about your reply.

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary variables, why shouldn't $b a = q a b$ also translate to $a b = q b a$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested [in comment by J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99970/make-own-rule-for-multiplication#comment271391_99970), [`NonCommutativeMultiply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html) might be useful here. Using [`//.`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) and two replacement rules you can get desired results.

```
$ncmRules = {
    (* Change b ** a to q a ** b. *)
    x___ ** b^n_. ** a^m_. ** y___ :> q^(n m) x ** a^m ** b^n ** y,
    (* Replace adjacent powers of same multiplicands by single power. *)
    x___ ** y_^n_. ** y_^m_. ** z___ :> x ** y^(n + m) ** z
   };



a ** b //. $ncmRules
(* a ** b *)
b ** a //. $ncmRules
(* q a ** b *)
b ** a ** a ** b //. $ncmRules
(* q^2 a^2 ** b^2 *)
b ** a ** b ** a ** a //. $ncmRules
(* q^5 a^3 ** b^2 *)
b ** a ** b ** b ** a //. $ncmRules
(* q^4 a^2 ** b^3 *)
```

Comment: I haven't check this page for a week, many thanks @jkuczm , it works

Answer (score 3):

Define your multiplication by two rules

```
CircleTimes[x_, y_] := q Times[x, y]
```

for 2 arguments and

```
CircleTimes[a___] := Module[{b, c},
 If[Length[{a}] > 2,
  b = CircleTimes [{a}[[1]], {a}[[2]] ];
  c = Join[{b}, {a}[[3 ;; All]] ];
 Apply[CircleTimes, c]]
 ]
```

It can be written shorter, here I separated into steps for clarity.

Test:

```
a⊗b⊗b⊗a
(*a^2 b^2 q^3*)

a⊗b a⊗b
(*a^2 b^2 q^2*)
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach similar to that of [yarchik](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9469/yarchik) but non-commutative is

```
CircleTimes[a, b] := Times[a, b]
CircleTimes[b, a] := q Times[a, b]
CircleTimes[z_, z_] := Times[z, z]
CircleTimes[z__] := Module[{zz = {z}, tem}, tem = CircleTimes @@ zz[[-2 ;; -1]]; 
    (CircleTimes @@ Join[zz[[1 ;; -3]], {First@tem}]) Rest@tem]
```

Then,

```
a⊗b
(* a b *)

b⊗a
(* a b q *)

a⊗b⊗b⊗a
(* a^2 b^2 q^2 *)
```

as specified in the Question.  Note that this definition of `CircleTimes` works only for `a` and `b`, because those are the only symbols defined in the Question.  It could be generalized to other symbols if the OP wished to provide rules for them.