# Saved notebook in .tex format: how to recover?

Tags: latex

I accidentally saved my notebook in the `.tex` format. Question, how can I get the original text back?

Comment: I have never used this feature before, but having looked at the output it produces, I'm afraid to say that recovering the original *Mathematica* inputs and outputs looks like it will be very awkward and fraught with error. It may be best to produce a PDF from the TeX file and then copy and paste the code into a new notebook.

Answer (score 3):

As described in the Mathematica documentation for [LaTex](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/LaTeX.html), it is possible to `Import` a `.tex` file into a notebook.  Suppose we `File>Save...`

```
CircleTimes[a, b] := Times[a, b]
CircleTimes[b, a] := q Times[a, b]
CircleTimes[z_, z_] := Times[z, z]
CircleTimes[z__] := Module[{zz = {z}, tem}, tem = CircleTimes @@ zz[[-2 ;; -1]]; 
  (CircleTimes @@ Join[zz[[1 ;; -3]], {First@tem}]) Rest@tem]
```

from [Question 99970](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99986/1063) to C:/Temp/99970.tex.  Then, it can be retrieved into a new notebook by

```
Import["C:/Temp/99970.tex", "NotebookObject"]
```

After `Cell>Convert To>InputForm`, the result is recognizable as close to the original code

```
CircleTimes [a,b]:==Times [a,b]
CircleTimes [b,a]:==q Times [a,b]
CircleTimes [z _,z _]:==Times [z,z]
CircleTimes [z __]:==Module[{zz=={z},tem},tem==CircleTimes@@zz[[-2;;-1]];
   (CircleTimes@@Join [zz [[1;;-3]],{First@tem}])Rest@tem]
```

but requires copying to a new notebook and modest editing, after which it executes as well as the original code.  I wish I could say that all code can be recovered so easily.  Code containing superscripts and subscripts is particularly messy.  Perhaps, others with greater experience than I in low-level coding can improve on this answer.