# Define a new rule for multiplication

Tags: function-construction, code-request, algebra, custom-notation

I am trying to implement a new rule for noncommutative multiplication:

$$ x * q^n * y \to q^n * x * y, $$ where $\ast$ stands for noncommutative multiplication and x and y are random products in variables a, b, c and q.

Few examples: $$
a * b^2 * c^2 * q * a \to q * a * b^2 * c^2 * a \\
q^2 * a * q \to q^3 * a \\
c^2 * b * q * a * q \to q^2 * c^2 * b * a \\
a * b^2 * q * b^3 * a \to q * a * b^5 * a \\
(q^2 * a + q * b + c) * (q * b) \to q^3 * a * b + q^2 * b^2 + q * c * b
$$

With help of [Make own rule for multiplication](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99970/make-own-rule-for-multiplication), I tried computing this:

```
$Rules = {
   (*Puts q^n first.*)
   x___ ** q^n_. ** y___ :> q^(n ) ** x ** y,
   (*Replace adjacent powers of same multiplicands by single power.*)
   x___ ** y_^n_. ** y_^m_. ** z___ :> x ** y^(n + m) ** z
   };
```

It works partially:

```
a ** b ** b ** a ** a //. $Rules
  a ** b^2 ** a^2

a ** q ** b //. $Rules
  q ** a ** b
```

But in some cases it doesn't work:

```
a ** q ** a //. $Rules
  q ** a ** a

q ** a ** q ** b //. $Rules
  q ** a ** q ** b

(q^2 + q ** b + c) ** (q ** b) //. $Rules
  q ** c ** b + q^2 ** q ** b + q ** b ** q ** b
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could modify to these replacements: `rules = {NonCommutativeMultiply[Longest[x___], y_^m_., y_^n_., z___] :>
    NonCommutativeMultiply[x, y^(m + n), z],
  NonCommutativeMultiply[x___, Plus[y_, z__], w___] :> 
   Distribute[NonCommutativeMultiply[x, Plus[y, z], w]],
  NonCommutativeMultiply[Longest[x___], q^n_., y___] :> 
   NonCommutativeMultiply[q^n, x, y]}`. I confess getting this all to work was a crazy-making experience. I've worked on some of the replacement rules and pattern-matching code, and still had no idea how sensitive the process is to rule ordering.

Comment: @daniel-lichtblau Thank you, that helped a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a personal preference I do not use Mathematica's `NonCommutativeMultiply` because it has almost no functionality. I found it easier to write my own version with the functionality (and only the functionality) I want. I adapted my version to include the factoring of `q` discussed in this question:

```
Needs["Notation`"]; (* Only needed if one wants to use an infix notation for NCM *)

ClearAll[NCM];

(* Default values and OneIdentity *)
NCM[]:=1;
Default[NCM]:=1
NCM[a_]:=a
Attributes[NCM]={OneIdentity};

(* Flatten out nested NCM *)
NCM[x___,NCM[y1_,y2__],z___]:=NCM[x,y1,y2,z] 

(* Distribute over *)
NCM[x___,f_[y1_,y2___],z___]/;MemberQ[{Plus,List,Equal,Rule,RuleDelayed},f]:=f@@Map[NCM[x,#,z]&,{y1,y2}]

(* Rotate q infront *)
NCM[x_,y__]:=Module[{xi,yi,cqy,cqx},
    xi={x}/.Power[q,n_]:>Sequence@@ConstantArray[q,n]/;IntegerQ[n]&&n>1;
    yi={y}/.Power[q,n_]:>Sequence@@ConstantArray[q,n]/;IntegerQ[n]&&n>1;
    cqx=Count[xi,q];
    cqy=Count[yi,q];
    NCM[Power[q,cqx+cqy],NCM@@DeleteCases[Join[xi,yi],q]]/;cqy>0
]

(* Generate powers *)
NCM[x___,y_,y_,z___]:=NCM[x,Power[y,2],z]
NCM[x___,Power[y_,n_],y_,z___]:=NCM[x,Power[y,n+1],z]
NCM[x___,y_,Power[y_,n_],z___]:=NCM[x,Power[y,n+1],z]
NCM[x___,Power[y_,n_],Power[y_,m_],z___]:=NCM[x,Power[y,n+m],z]

(** Formating [OPTIONAL] **)
NCM/:MakeBoxes[NCM[a_,b__],StandardForm]/;BoxForm`UseIcons:=With[{box=ToBoxes[Row[{a,b}," "]]},InterpretationBox[box,NCM[a,b]]]

(* Use ** as infix input for NCM [OPTIONAL] *)
InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper["**"],NCM];
```

The `Notation` package is optional as is the custom `StandardForm`. The examples from the question all seem to work fine

```
a**b**b**a**a (*=> a**b^2**a^2 *)
a**q**b (*=> q**a**b *)
a**q**a (*=> q**a^2 *)
q**a**q**b(*=> q^2**a**b *)
(q^2+q**b+c)**(q**b) (*=> q^2**b + q^3**b + q**c**b *)
```

> [image: Result]

Depending on what one wants to archive I would however argue against using `Power` in `NCM` and if `q` is supposed to be a simple commutative object (*e.g.* a Number) an argument can be made to factor out these commutative coefficients resulting in something like `q*a**b`.

Comment: thank you, it works!