# Plug in values in symbolic expressions

Tags: symbolic, algebra, custom-notation, quaternions

With the help of answers on this post: [new rule for noncommutative multiplication](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266970/define-a-new-rule-for-multiplication),  defined new noncommutative multiplication:

```
Needs["Notation`"]; (* Only needed if one wants to use an infix notation for NCM *)

ClearAll[NCM];

(* Default values and OneIdentity *)
NCM[]:=1;
Default[NCM]:=1
NCM[a_]:=a
Attributes[NCM]={OneIdentity};

(* Flatten out nested NCM *)
NCM[x___,NCM[y1_,y2__],z___]:=NCM[x,y1,y2,z] 

(* Distribute over *)
NCM[x___,f_[y1_,y2___],z___]/;MemberQ[{Plus,List,Equal,Rule,RuleDelayed},f]:=f@@Map[NCM[x,#,z]&,{y1,y2}]

(* Rotate q infront *)
NCM[x_,y__]:=Module[{xi,yi,cqy,cqx},
    xi={x}/.Power[q,n_]:>Sequence@@ConstantArray[q,n]/;IntegerQ[n]&&n>1;
    yi={y}/.Power[q,n_]:>Sequence@@ConstantArray[q,n]/;IntegerQ[n]&&n>1;
    cqx=Count[xi,q];
    cqy=Count[yi,q];
    NCM[Power[q,cqx+cqy],NCM@@DeleteCases[Join[xi,yi],q]]/;cqy>0
]

(** Formating [OPTIONAL] **)
NCM/:MakeBoxes[NCM[a_,b__],StandardForm]/;BoxForm`UseIcons:=With[{box=ToBoxes[Row[{a,b}," "]]},InterpretationBox[box,NCM[a,b]]]

(* Use ** as infix input for NCM [OPTIONAL] *)
InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper["**"],NCM];
```

Symbolically it works great. However, I don't know how to plug values in. For example:

```
a ** q ** a
    NCM[q, a, a]  
    (this is fine)

a ** q ** a //. {a -> Quaternion[0, 1, 0, 0], q -> Quaternion[0, 0, 1, 0]}
    NCM[Quaternions`Quaternion[0, 0, 1, 0], Quaternions`Quaternion[0, 1, 0, 0], Quaternions`Quaternion[0, 1, 0, 0]] 
    (this is not fully evaluated)
```

I also imported package Quaternions`.

So my question is, when the symbolic calculation is complete, how to then plug in values (quaternions) so that the result will be one quaternion?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You need to add a definition for something like `NCM[w___, x_Quaternions`Quaternion, y_Quaternions`Quaternion, z___]`, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks! That helped.